# How to view all users those have clicked on Facebook LIKE for a website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

This is very common thing to have Facebook-Like button on a page of website. But what we can do to view all users who has been liked our website. For example you can visit [http://teckstack.com][1].

[1]: http://teckstack.com and please suggest me to do this.

It's very big question to Facebook also that we facebook has launched api for a long ago but I really fagged out by searching to get my solution.

Anybody can help?

Comment: On your facebook page you can view it all right?

Comment: I am not talking about Facebook-FanPage-Like, I am talking about website url like. Do you have answer for this bro?